# Connect button disabled Azure Linux RDP endpoint

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, azure

I have Linux VM on Azure deployed with Hortonworks Sandbox VM and want install Linux desktop. 
Following this tutorial https://linuxonazure.wordpress.com/category/linux-on-azure-application/linux-on-azure-vm-with-desktop/ got to the point of endpoint configuration. Button "Connect" should become enabled, but it is still disabled. What's more, the parameters to be set (UI) of endpoint in Azure changed and I am not sure of them. Any help appreciated.
 [Image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frm6d.jpg)

Comment: Does the VM have a public IP? Check the Network configuration, give the machine a public IP, save, wait for a couple of minutes while the networking is redone and then the Connect button should turn on.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the URL you're using, do the following and it will work like charm:

```
sudo passwd root
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop 
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

Open port 3389 from the endpoints on portal or from Resource Security Group and your Connect button will be there.